# Wrongly use Arrays in VB - Not sure how to solve

Tags: arrays, vb.net

It's been such a long time since i touch vb.net and I am having a problem.. it should be a simple one but I am lost.
I want to create a loop string but before that I am trying to learn how to use the string array.

The following code is what I have but there is always error at the line g(1,0)=t
It is not an object instance. How can this be done?

Code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim g(,) As String
        Dim t As String = "ok"
        g(1, 0) = t
        MsgBox(g(1, 0))
    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you wanting to add to this array, or is it going to be a set size. As it stands right now you are not dimensioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim g(,) As String= {{"Hai","Hello"},{"ok","then"}}
        MsgBox(g(1, 0))
    End Sub
```

For more information refer [this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sxy840k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

**EDIT:**

You can traverse your array like this

```
   Dim g(1,1) As String

   for i as integer=0 to 1
      for j as integer=0 to 1
         g(i,j)="Your text"
      next
   next
```

Comment: Hmm...how do I add this into a loop? Like every loop have new {}

Comment: @user2041851 do you need like this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your array a size. For example:

```
Dim g(100, 100) As String
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wak0wfyt.aspx#BKMK_CreatingAnArray

Comment: yea..that's the usual practice but i was thinking if it is flexible like php where you can just keep adding array in a loop (like retrieving data from database)

Answer (score 1):

Use the REDIM statement (re-dimension) before you attempt to re-dimension (change the size) of your array.

something like

```
REDIM g(10, 10)
```

Comment: Oh thats great, usually when defining the array you wold put a nuber there to represent the maximum size of the array like g(100) or g(100,100) for a two dimensional array or g(10,10,100) for a three dimensional array. and when you want a dynamic array you leave the value out like g() or g(,) and when you re-dimension you use the REDIM command to change the array boundaries